# Function can't find column name in tibble

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tibble

I'm trying to create a function that uses dplyr syntax to manipulate data, but the function can't find the column names.

```
    # example code below
    library(dplyr)
    

    # create sample data
    ex.dat = data.frame(ex.IV = c(rep(1,50),
                          rep(2,50)), 
                  ex.DV = c(rnorm(n = 50, mean = 100, sd = 15),
                         rnorm(n = 50, mean = 115, sd = 15)))
    

    # create simple function that finds mean and sd from sample data
    ex.func = function(data,predictor,predicted){
      as.tibble(data) %>%
        group_by(predictor) %>%
        summarise(
          M = mean(predicted),
          SD = sd(predicted)
        )
    }
    
    # run function with sample data
    ex.func(data = ex.dat, predictor = ex.IV, predicted = ex.DV)
```

This produces the following error: "Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`. Column `predictor` is not found."

I don't understand why the function isn't assigning `ex.IV` to `predictor`.

Running the same code without involving a function, of course, has no issues, e.g.,

```
    as.tibble(ex.dat) %>%
     group_by(ex.IV) %>%
     summarise(
       M = mean(ex.DV),
       SD = sd(ex.DV))
```

produces the intended result, so the issue must reside in the function formatting.

Workarounds like:

```
ex.func(data = ex.dat, predictor = ex.dat$ex.IV, predicted = ex.dat$ex.DV)
ex.func(data = ex.dat, predictor = data$ex.IV, predicted = data$ex.DV)
```

receive the same errors.

Clearly I'm not understanding some basic operations of `function()`. I'd appreciate some pointers.

Comment: This issue has less to do with `function()` and more to do with programming with **dplyr** verbs specifically. Since **dplyr** uses non-standard evaluation, programming gets a little tricky. The [Programming with **dplyr** article](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) is useful for some background and examples. The tools for programming come from package **rlang**, and you can see a brief overview at [this blog post](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/).

Comment: That blog post is perfectly relevant, and gives useful context around akrun's answer below. Thanks for the share!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could make use of the curly-curly (`{{}}`) operator as the input argument are unquoted

```
ex.func <- function(data, predictor, predicted){
      as.tibble(data) %>%
        group_by({{predictor}}) %>%
        summarise(
          M = mean({{predicted}}),
          SD = sd({{predicted}})
        )
    }
```

Now run as

```
ex.func(data = ex.dat, predictor = ex.IV, predicted = ex.DV)
```

---

If we need flexible option is the argument passed can be either quoted or unquoted, then we may need to convert to symbol with `ensym` and evaluate (`!!`

```
ex.func <- function(data, predictor, predicted){
     predictor <- rlang::ensym(predictor)
     predicted <- rlang::ensym(predicted)
      as.tibble(data) %>%
        group_by(!!predictor) %>%
        summarise(
          M = mean(!!predicted),
          SD = sd(!!predicted)
        )
    }
```

Then, we can call either as

```
ex.func(data = ex.dat, predictor = ex.IV, predicted = ex.DV)
```

Or

```
ex.func(data = ex.dat, predictor = "ex.IV", predicted = "ex.DV")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the input argument are unquoted"? Is this to imply that the call should be ex.func(data = "ex.dat", predictor = "ex.IV", predicted = "ex.DV") or something similar? Wondering if the {{}} is a workaround for a better practice I could adopt.

Comment: @sachem87 I meant the predictor and predicted passed are `ex.IV`, `ex.DV` instead of `"ex.IV"`, `"ex.DV"`.  The data object should be passed unquoted `ex.dat`

Comment: @sachem87 the call for the solution in my post would be just `ex.func(data = ex.dat, predictor = ex.IV, predicted = ex.DV)`

Comment: The functions I am interested in using are much longer/complex than the sample code, and they reference the variables many times, so a solution on the call side rather than {{}} around the in-function references would be much cleaner, does this exist? Or is {{}} within functions unavoidable?

Comment: Thanks for your help akrun. I think I'll be seeing more braces than a dentist from here on out.

Comment: @sachem87 The update I provided is more flexible as this function can be also used in a list by looping over names as a string